# SQLite: trigger to check newly inserted row against limits in another table

Tags: sqlite, inner-join, database-trigger

I have a database with the following schema:

```
Sensors (
ID      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
                UNIQUE
                NOT NULL,
SITE_ID INTEGER REFERENCES Sites (ID) 
                NOT NULL,
NAME    TEXT    UNIQUE
                NOT NULL
);

Sites (
ID   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
             UNIQUE
             NOT NULL,
NAME TEXT    UNIQUE
             NOT NULL
);

Data (
SENSOR_ID INTEGER  REFERENCES Sensors (ID) 
                   NOT NULL,
COUNT     INTEGER  NOT NULL,
TIME      DATETIME NOT NULL,
TYPE      TEXT     NOT NULL,
VALUE     REAL     NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (
    SENSOR_ID,
    COUNT,
    TIME,
    TYPE
)
);

Limits (
SITE_ID INTEGER REFERENCES Sites (ID) 
                NOT NULL,
TYPE    TEXT    NOT NULL,
HIGH    REAL    NOT NULL,
LOW     REAL    NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (
    SITE_ID,
    TYPE
)
);
```

Data contains all the data for all sensors and sites, Data has a few different types. The limits have a row for each type of data for each of the sites. I want to create a table identical to Data (called Warnings) containing only the rows where the value lies outside of the limits in Limit.

I want to do this with a trigger because the limits can change and the rows are added to data sporadically.

Here's my best attempt so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER VALUE_OUT_OF_RANGE 
AFTER INSERT
ON Data
WHEN NEW.VALUE < (SELECT Limits.LOW FROM Limits INNER JOIN Sensors ON (Sensors.SITE_ID = Limits.SITE_ID) WHERE (Sensors.ID = NEW.SENSOR_ID AND Limits.TYPE = NEW.TYPE))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Warnings(SENSOR_ID, COUNT, TIME, TYPE, VALUE) VALUES(NEW.SENSOR_ID, NEW.COUNT, NEW.TIME, NEW.TYPE, NEW.VALUE);
END;
```

In my attempt I've only checked against the lower limit, in the final trigger I would like to check that the value is between the LOW and HIGH limits.
I've tried the Select statement seperately and I get the data that I am looking for.
Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution that works.
Posting it in case it helps anyone.

```
CREATE TRIGGER VALUE_OUT_OF_RANGE
    AFTER INSERT
    ON Data
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN NEW.VALUE < (
                           SELECT Limits.LOW
                             FROM Limits
                                  JOIN
                                  Sensors ON (Sensors.SITE_ID = Limits.SITE_ID) 
                            WHERE (Sensors.ID = NEW.Sensor_ID AND 
                                   Limits.TYPE = NEW.TYPE) 
                            LIMIT 1
                       )
    OR 
    NEW.VALUE > (
                           SELECT Limits.HIGH
                             FROM Limits
                                  JOIN
                                  Sensors ON (Sensors.SITE_ID = Limits.SITE_ID) 
                            WHERE (Sensors.ID = NEW.Sensor_ID AND 
                                   Limits.TYPE = NEW.TYPE) 
                            LIMIT 1
                       )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Warnings (
                         SENSOR_ID,
                         COUNT,
                         TIME,
                         TYPE,
                         VALUE
                     )
                     VALUES (
                         NEW.SENSOR_ID,
                         NEW.COUNT,
                         NEW.TIME,
                         NEW.TYPE,
                         NEW.VALUE
                     );
END;
```